# How do I create a regex to remove underscore

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 with Razor. I can't figure out how to code a string extension regex to take this:

> This_is_some_text

to display:

> This is some text

I set up some enums for a drop down list, so they appear thusly (obviously I can't create an enum with a space):

```
public enum MyProperty 
{
     This_is_some_text, 
     This_is_some_other_text
}
```

I just cannot figure out the regex is to do what I want if I am doing this:

```
 public static string EnumToDisplay(this string str)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(str, "[What is the regex I should use?]");
        }
```

As a bonus for me I would also like to add a period "." to the end of the enum. The reason for this is that I have OCD and my enums are taking the form of short sentences. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use regular expressions? A very wise man once said, I quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

How about using the [`[Display]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) attribute which is kinda designed exactly for this purpose:

```
public enum MyProperty
{
    [Display(Name = "This is some super text")]
    This_is_some_text,

    [Display(Name = "And this is some other text")]
    This_is_some_other_text
}
```

and then writing a custom Html helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (!typeof(TProperty).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("sorry this helper is inteded to be used with enum types");
        }

        var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;

        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.Model == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }


        var field = typeof(TProperty).GetField(expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model).ToString());
        if (field == null)
        {
            return new HtmlString(htmlHelper.Encode(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.ToString()));
        }

        var display = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
        if (display == null)
        {
            return new HtmlString(htmlHelper.Encode(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model.ToString()));
        }

        return new HtmlString(htmlHelper.Encode(display.Name));
    }
}
```

So now assuming you have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyProperty Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Foo = MyProperty.This_is_some_other_text
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

you could use the custom helper we just wrote in the view to display a user friendly text that we might have associated to an ugly enum. Hey, now you could even have this working with globalization and multiple languages using resources:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayForEnum(x => x.Foo)
```

Comment: My answer is the quick-and-dirty method, but this is definitely the proper solution.  If you go with this, you can easily add other non-alpha characters as well, like parens or apostrophes.

Comment: This is incredible! Thanks. Going to implement then mark if appropriate.

Comment: This was a great solution. And the suggestion about working with globalization! +++++

Comment: Darin, is there a way to display them individually without having to do it in the controller? So, for example, I might be able to do something like `@Html.DisplayForEnum(x => x.Foo.Enum1)`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) for this?  RegEx seems a bit overkill.

```
public static string EnumToDisplay(this string str)
{
    return str.Replace('_', ' ') + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about asp.net - but there *should* be a really simple method that replaces one character with another char. Like:

```
String.replace( myString, '_',' ' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replacement pattern which is also called substitution.

You can find graet info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx

Good luck